Clarification of the method in topological data analysis
I want to detect the stock price crashes using topological data analysis. For example I have taken an excel file named tesla with columns date,open,high,low,close and volume. I want the time series of the Close column. Now first I apply takens embedding theorem , then apply the slinging window. Then use rips complex to detect holes.
I have used some research papers on tda for gaining this information, but unable to understand why the thing s are implemented .
Can anyone explain what is going on ?

The general idea behind using topological data analysis on time series data is that -- according to Taken's embedding theorem -- if there is an attractor in a dynamical system, then it can be embedded in high-dimensional space by a sliding-window embedding. This embedding is smooth, and topological -- that is, the overall connectivity of the attractor is maintained (i.e. is it a cycle? is it a torus?).
Applying topological data analysis methods to the resulting object allow you to get measurements of the topological properties of the embedding that you have constructed. For example, a cyclical attractor (stable oscillator) will simply look like a one-dimensional hole ($\beta_1 = 1$). If you have two fairly independent oscillatory behaviors you may expect a torus ($\beta_1 = 2, \beta_2 = 1$).
For example, Suppose there is a simple seasonal cycle in your time series and nothing else, you would expect to see a clear $\beta_1 = 1$.
